# "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find library"

Tags: gcc, linker, fortran, ld, gfortran

This is my first time trying to compile FORTRAN code using a makefile. The OS is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit. I encountered the following errors:

```
gfortran  -o przm3123.exe canopy.o chem.o cnfuns.o cropdate.o datemod.o debug.o debug_cn.o f2kcli.o floatcmp.o furrow.o general.o i_errchk.o infnan.o inivar.o ioluns.o iosubs.o lambertw.o m_readvars.o utils.o wind.o fcscnc.o przm3.o rsexec.o rsinp1.o rsinp2.o rsinp3.o rsmcar.o rsmisc.o rsprz1.o rsprz2.o rsprz3.o rsprzn.o rsutil.o rsvado.o -L ../libanne4.0/lib -lwdm -ladwdm -lutil
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwdm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ladwdm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [przm3123.exe] Error 1
```

The key element in the makefile is:

```
przm2_LIBS = -L ../libanne4.0/lib -lwdm -ladwdm -lutil
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this error? Should I try other compilers?

Comment: The first thing I would check is if you actually have `libwdm.so` and `libadwdm.so`. I would assume they should be in this `libanne4.0/lib` directory.

Comment: Yes,     `libwdm.a`     and `libadwdm.a` are there.

Comment: Oh, static libraries. Can you try this in your makefile? `przm2_LIBS = -L../libanne4.0/lib -Wl,-Bdynamic -lutil -Wl,-Bstatic -lwdm -ladwdm` - I assume `util` is `libutil.so` (a shared library) since it didn't complain about that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried your suggestion. Here are the new outputs: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwdm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ladwdm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s`

Comment: I think alk might be onto something (might be a path issue). Can you show a directory listing of the libraries in `libanne4.0/lib`? Also, change the line to `przm2_LIBS = -L(path/to/libanne4.0/lib) -Wl,-Bstatic -lwdm -ladwdm -Wl,-Bdynamic -lutil` - the `lgcc_s` stuff was because I set the linker to use static linking as the last thing, so this changes it to use dynamic linking.

Comment: @birryree: tried to offer the absolute path and use the new arguments. It complained something else: `gfortran: error: unrecognized option ‘-wdm’`. Then I removed `-wdm` option. Similar error msg '/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ladwdm
'

Comment: Sorry, you must have used my comment before I edited it, it was supposed to be `-lwdm`. The really, really hacky method is to use full paths to link, like this: `gfortran (the regular stuff) /path/to/libwdm.a /path/to/libadwdm.a -L../libanne4.0/lib -util`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried `/home/th/Desktop/przm_ed/libanne4.0/lib/wdmlib.a /home/th/Desktop/przm_ed/libanne4.0/lib/adwdmlib.a  /home/th/Desktop/przm_ed/libanne4.0/lib/utillib.a` and the responses are `/home/th/Desktop/przm_ed/libanne4.0/lib/utillib.a(dttmsn.o): In function `sydate_':
dttmsn.f:(.text+0x2c5): undefined reference to `idate_'
/home/th/Desktop/przm_ed/libanne4.0/lib/utillib.a(dttmsn.o): In function `sytime_':
dttmsn.f:(.text+0x32c): undefined reference to `itime_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status` Does that mean those paths are accepted?

Comment: It would appear so, but now you're getting missing definition problems, as `idate_` and `itime_` aren't found. I don't know where those are from, might be gfortran specific.

Answer (score 10):

As `../libanne4.0/lib` is a relative path, you might try changing it into an absolute one.

Also you could check whether the linker process has the rights to access and read the libs.

---

Update: To have the linker find a library specified using the option `-l<name>` the name of the libray shall be `lib<name>.[a|so]` and the parameter to `-L` should point the path were the library is located.

`-L` needs to preceed it's `-l` option(s).

One could specify `-l` and/or `-L` multiple  times.

Comment: Provided the absolute path, but same error. I tried `ld adwdmlib.a` and got the following errors: `ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address` thanks

Comment: adwdmlib.a is a library I need to include. Based on the L and l rule you mendtioned. Does that mean `przm2_LIBS = -L ../libanne4.0/lib -lwdm -ladwdm -lutil` does not work because the name of those libs are not correct?

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with the name "adwdmlib.a".  A linking flag "-l adwdm" will tell the compiler to expect a lib file with the name "libadwdm.a", not "adwdmlib.a".  Is this helpful or relevant?  If your library name is "adwdmlib.a", that is probably why your linker can't find it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried to rename those libs, but linker still could not find them.